# Accessing a local variable outside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this will be a very obvious answer for must of you guys, but please keep in mind that I recently started learning JS and this is one of the only principle that I don't understand.

I am trying to find a way to make a variable inside a function be global. I will show you my code so maybe you will understand:

```
$('#inputSubmit').click(function() {
    addText_1("Good, your character's name is " + getInput() + ".");
    condition1 = true;
});
if(condition1 == true) {
   addText_1("Now")
```

};

I am trying to find a way so that the if statement can access the condition1 variable in order to execute the folowing line of code.

For some reason, the if statement cannot access the condition1 value inside the click event.

Also, maybe you know a better way that this way to do what I am trying to do. Basically, I am trying to write code that will use the addText_1 function if the #inputSubmit was clicked. If you know another way of doing this, I would like to know.

Thank you very much for the help and I am sorry if this question wasn't very clear.

Comment: Good news!  Your "condition1" variable isn't a local variable, because you forgot to declare it with `var`.  (I'm being mean.) In the case of a *real* local variable, you can't without the function involved wanting you to be able to do that.

Comment: Local variables are local. That's the point. If you want, move it a level up to be less local, that will create a closure.

Comment: Oh, alright, but is there a reason that my if statement is not executing?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is conceptually wrong. The click handler executes on click (of whatever). The lines of code that follow the definition of the click handler run immediately after the handler is *attached*, not after it is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the basic problem is the time axis of your code. althought the code is build with 2 blocks, the last block actually run BEFORE the first block

```
$('#inputSubmit').click(function() // occurs when the user click (#2)
{
    addText_1("Good, your character's name is " + getInput() + ".");
    condition1 = true;
});

if(condition1 == true) // occurs when the page load (#1)
{
   addText_1("Now")
};
```

i guess what you are trying to do is:

```
$('#inputSubmit').click(function() 
{
    addText_1("Good, your character's name is " + getInput() + ".");
    addText_1("Now")
});
```